# Is a substitution always required to change the limits of an integral?

Tags: definite-integrals, substitution

`For example:`

Suppose we have an impulsive force $f(t)$ lasting from $t=t_0$ until $t=t_1$ which is applied to a mass $m$. Then by Newtons Second law we have $$\int_{t=t_0}^{t=t_1}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=\int_\color{red}{t=t_0}^\color{red}{t=t_1}m\color{blue}{\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}}\mathrm{d}t=\int_\color{red}{v=v_0}^\color{red}{v=v_1}m\,\mathrm{d}v=m(v_1-v_0)\tag{1}$$

What I can't understand is; What substitution was made to allow the limits marked $\color{red}{\mathrm{red}}$ to change from $t$ to $v$.

I thought it might be due to $$\color{blue}{\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}}=\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}x}\cdot \underbrace{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}}_{\Large{\color{#180}{=v}}}=v\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}x}$$ by the chain rule.

But it is something much simpler than this, and I believe I am over-thinking it too much. Could someone please tell me what substitution was made to change the limits marked $\color{red}{\mathrm{red}}$ in equation $(1)$?

---

### Edit:

Comments below seem to indicate that one can simply change the limits of integration to make the integral dimensionally correct. But I consider this to be a less rigorous approach, and I was taught that integral limits **must** be changed via a substitution. So I still need to know what substitution was made?

Thanks again.

Comment: The dt is just cancelled nothing more i think

Comment: @Archis Thanks for your reply; I spotted that also but it still doesn't explain _how_ the $t$ limit changed to $v$

Comment: So it becomes $m\int dv$ so our integration turns wrt velocity

Comment: @ArchisWelankar But it still has $t$ limits. Just because the integrand is with respect to $v$ it doesn't automatically change the limits from $t$ to $v$. Or does it?

Comment: It does or that would change dimensions in physics $m/s=s$ !! Which is surely incorrect

Comment: @ArchisWelankar That would have to be the case for it to be dimensionally correct, but I still believe the limits have to be transformed via a substitution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental reason to change the limits of integration is that
the *variable* of integration has changed.

Substitution is an obvious case in which this is likely to occur.
For example, substitute $u = x - 2$ in $\int (x - 2) dx$:
$$
\int_0^2 (x - 2) dx = \int_{-2}^0 u\; du.
$$
The intuition I follow on this is that the start of the integral occurs
"when $x=0$" and ends "when $x=2$".
But "when" $x=0$, it must also be true that $u=-2$,
and "when" $x=2$, it must also be true that $u=0$.
So *in terms of $u$,* the integral needs to start 
"when $u=-2$" and end "when $u=0$".

A more rigorous treatment would take $x - 2$ as a function over
the domain $[0,2]$ and transform it; but transforming the function
also transforms its domain, so $x - 2$ over the domain $[0,2]$
transforms to $u$ over the domain $[-2,0]$.

*Anything* that changes the integration variable of a definite integral
also has to be reflected in the limits of integration,
because just as with any substitution, you're integrating a (possibly)
different function over a (possibly) different domain.
That is, if the integrand changes from $f(t)dt$ to $h(v)dv$
(even if $h(v)$ is a constant function, as it is in the question),
the integral over $v$ needs to start and end at $v$-values that are
correctly matched to the $t$-values at which the integral over $t$
started and ended.

---

Note that in any change of variables, regardless of whether we achieve it
by first writing down an explicit substitution formula (such as $u = x - 2$),
has to account for the derivative of the new variable of integration
with respect to the old one. For a substitution from $t$ to $u$ via the 
equation $u = h(t)$, the derivative of the new w.r.t. the old is 
$\dfrac{du}{dt} = h'(t)$
and it is accounted for in the rule
$$
\int g(h(t))\, h'(t)\, dt = g(u)\, du.
$$
As far as I know, a change of variables must not break this rule,
so there must somehow be a substitution $u = h(t)$ that can explain it.

In the integral in the question, 
$f(t) = m \dfrac{d^2 x}{dt^2}$. 
If $\dfrac{dx}{dt} = v = h(t)$ 
and if $g$ is the constant function with value $m$, 
then $\dfrac{d^2 x}{dt^2} = \dfrac{dv}{dt} = h'(t)$ and $g(h(t)) = m$, so
$$
\int m \frac{dv}{dt} \, dt 
 = \int g(h(t))\, h'(t)\, dt
 = \int g(v)\, dv = \int m \, dv.
$$
The definite integral follows the same rule but also has to make the
corresponding change to the interval of integration:
$$
\int_{t_0}^{t_1} g(h(t))\, h'(t)\, dt
 = \int_{h(t_0)}^{h(t_1)} g(v)\, dv;
$$
setting $v_0=h(t_0)$ and $v_1=h(t_1)$,
$$
\int_{t_0}^{t_1} m \frac{dv}{dt} \, dt 
 = \int_{h(t_0)}^{h(t_1)} m \, dv
 = \int_{v_0}^{v_1} m \, dv.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer; So in summary you're saying a substitution is not _always_ required to change the limits of an integral since we can simply change the limits intuitively?

Comment: I think a substitution _is_ required in the sense that any legitimate change of variables has to obey the same rules that a substitution does. I just don't think it's always necessary to write a substitution rule in the form $v=g(t)$ in order to do a change of variables and correctly set the bounds. In fact, I think the substitution in this case is $v=dx/dt$, but I don't find this really helps me to see that $t=t_0$ must be replaced by $v=v_0$.

Comment: I just really need to know how the substitution  $v=\cfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}$ will work, since we then have $\displaystyle\int_{t=t_0}^{t=t_1}m{\cfrac{\mathrm{d}^2 x}{\mathrm{d}t^2}}\mathrm{d}t$. Could you please show me how this would transform the integral? Thanks again.

Comment: OK, I've appended some paragraphs to the answer giving an explicit substitution to explain the change of variables.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from your prefactors (like mass), when you integrate $dv/dt$ you integrate the derivative of a function, hence we all know the answer is the function itself. Hence: $$\int_{t_0}^{t_1}  v^{\prime}(t)\, dt = v(t_1) - v(t_0)$$